# Grails project with no Build.Groovy file. How to add plugins

Tags: java, gradle, grails, groovy, redis

I am currently trying to add Redis Hibernate cache plugin to my Grails/Gradle project. However, in the configuration folder, there exists no BuildConfig.Groovy file, and the instructions instruct to add the dependency and other configs to this file. 
This project was not created by me, however I am working on it as a collaborator.
There exists a Build.Gradle file, but there are no instructions on how to configure/add this dependency here. 
Below is a screenshot of the instructions on the Grails Plugins page.[image]

Comment: `BuildConfig.groovy` is only relevant to Grails 1 and 2 apps.  In particular, it is not relevant to Grails 3 apps.   Are you working with a Grails 3 project?

Comment: AH I see. Thanks a bunch, I did not know that fact about the versions(1 and 2 vs 3). I am in fact working with Grails 3.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a build.gradle file then you're in grails 3 as far as I know.  You may want to view documentation here: http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/ctoestreich/redis but in short, you will need to add a compile-time dependency there rather than BuildConfig.groovy.

Add or modify your dependencies block to contain:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:redis:2.0.5'
}
```

Or any other plugins as needed.

Comment: "If you have a build.gradle file then you're in grails 3 as far as I know." - That is likely the case, but not certain.  You can build Grails 2 apps with Gradle, we just don't generate a Gradle build by default for Grails 2.  See http://grails.github.io/grails-gradle-plugin/docs/manual/.

Comment: Interesting!  I did not know that but am glad to learn it.  @william-tolliver if you are in fact using grails 1 or 2, then my answer is probably still marginally valid but the 2.x version of the redis plugin will not work for you, so update accordingly.

Comment: @Daniel I am using Grails 3. I simply did not know that fact about the versions using different files for the same purpose this way.

Comment: No problem; I didn't know it was possible to use gradle in versions 1 and 2!  Learning as we go here.  :-)